# I have two different graphs. Should I use one legend or two legends in this case?

Tags: usability, gui-design, mobile, mobile-application, ux-field

I have two graphs that follow the same legend. I am wondering if should use one legend for both graphs (screenshot A) or one legend for each graph. (screenshot B) I don't want to clutter the design with extra legends if I can help it, but at the same time I feel that it will be easier/faster to examine each graph and see what colors represent each category. Any suggestions?

Screenshot A:

[image]

Screenshot B:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on this prototype, it seems to me that **option B** is the correct choice. The two sections in question are clearly separated, and according to the [**Gestalt's Law of Pragnanz**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping) (also known as Grouping), one group of legends should belong to a graph, while the other group should not. Thus, it is necessary to use two separate groups of legends.

In addition, users may need to scroll to see both sections, which could be problematic. Furthermore, [**assistive technologies**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_technology#Visual_impairments) may not recognize the legends as belonging to the same group, potentially causing accessibility issues.

PS: of course you could use only one group of legends, but the UI should be designed in a different way.